Problems with the python libraries speedtest/speedtes-cli and tkinter when using cx_freeze
I have written a script to perform a number of broadband speed tests using python/tkinter and the speedtest libraries (speedtest/speedtest-cli). The program works as expected when run as a normal python script. I can create an exe file using cx_freeze and it creates everything as per normal. When I run the exe file I get the following traceback...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File
"c:\@python\@w4itdev\lib\site-packages\speedtest.py",
line 156, in <module>
import_builtin___
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__builtin__
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File
"C:\@python\@w4itdev\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscript s_startup__.py", line 141, in run module_init.run(name + "__main__")
File
"C:\@python\@w4itdev\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscript
s\console.py", line 25, in run
exec(code, main_globals) File "st.py", line 2, in <module>
File "c:\@python\@w4itdev\lib\site-packages\speedtest.py", line 179, in <module>
_py3_utf8_stdout= _Py3Utf8Output(sys.stdout)
File "c:\@python\@w4itdev\lib\site-packages\speedtest.py", line 166, in __init__
buf FilelO(f.fileno), 'w')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'

I have grabbed a simpler python script that does a similar job to test whether I had made mistakes with my code. This gave the same results. To keep things simple I have included the simple script as opposed to my original.
from tkinter import *
from speedtest import Speedtest

def update_text():
    speed_test = Speedtest()
    download = speed_test.download()
    upload = speed_test.upload()
    download_speed = round(download / (10**6), 2)
    upload_speed = round(upload / (10**6), 2)
    down_label.config(text= "Download Speed - " + str(download_speed) + "Mbps") 
    up_label.config(text= "Upload Speed - " + str(upload_speed) + "Mbps") 


root = Tk()
root.title("Internet Speed Tracker")
root.geometry('300x300')
button = Button(root, text="Get Speed", width=30, command=update_text)
button.pack()
down_label = Label(root, text="")
down_label.pack()
up_label = Label(root, text="")
up_label.pack()

root.mainloop()

It would appear, though I'm no expert, that the error is due to a combination of tkinter/speedtest/cx_freeze and ultimately stdout.

Cannot reproduce issue using cx-freeze 7.2.0 with Python 3.12.4 in Windows 11.  How did you execute cxfreeze?

The Speedtest library uses the builtin module, which is available in Python 2 but not in Python 3. cx_Freeze attempts to run the script in a Python 3 environment, which causes the error.
Instead of cx_Freeze, try using pyinstaller or py2exe to create the executable.

Huh? I thought it considers using __builtin__, then uses builtins if it's not available.

I find pyinstaller triggers an antivirus threat way more often than cx_freeze does so I tend to use cx_freeze.

It seems like you have configured cxfreeze to create a GUI-based (or windowed) application which does not connect to a standard console, so sys.stdout and sys.stderr are set to None.  It is the cause of the exception raised when importing speedtest module.
Either changing cxfreeze to create a console-based application or setting sys.stdout and sys.stderr to an open null device as below before importing speedtest module:
...
import os, sys
sys.stderr = sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'wb')
from speedtest import Speedtest
...

